# How can I highlight .htaccess code in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, htaccess

How can I highlight `.htaccess` code?

I downloaded [this XML](http://plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/userDefineLang_Apache2.xml) file and I copy and pasted file content to `userDefinedLanguage.xml` inside my install directory.

According to the documentation found [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Languages) I need to do the following:

> "You get the tool for creating or changing your language from View -> User Define Dialog.... Be patient, it can take quite a while to load."

The problem is my Notepad++ menu looks like this:

[image]

I'm on the latest version and I don't see the "User Define Dialog" option under *View* or *Settings*

How can I import this file and make `.htaccess` files highlighted?

Comment: note for editors:userDefinedLanguage is a xml file, not a floder

Comment: I have no idea what a floder is, but if an editor made a mistake, just correct it.   Feel free to correct that mistake now that you know you can edit your own question.

Comment: I not realy like add correction after correction, (my english otherwise realy bad, maybe after I edit the question, the quality colud be very bad )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You get the tool for creating or changing your language from View -> User Define Dialog

It looks like the documentation you are linking to is out of date. It is now under the "Language" menu item.

In my version of Notepad v6.7.7 you need to:

- Goto menu "Language" > "Define your language..."

  [image]
- You will then see the "User Defined Language" dialog. Click "Import...:

  [image]
- After you have imported your language, select it from menu "Language".
- You may need to goto menu "Settings" > "Preferences" > "Language Menu" to add your language to the menu "Language".

  [image]

Comment: Ah tank you!
Note:
I also neded to select language from language menu after I imported.
Please create a line from this and after I acept your answer :)

Comment: @InBug No problem ;) Answer updated.

Answer (score 7):

I wasn't sure exactly how to work this out. A little more searching and I dug up exactly what I was looking for.

**Notepad++ Apache httpd.conf .htaccess Syntax Highlighting**

Download
http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/userDefineLang_Apache2.xml

> View > User Defined Dialogue > [ Import ]
>   http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/25/creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad.aspx

Comment: You might want to change your comment to point to "Language > Define your language > [Import]", as that more closely resembles the user interface